# Nuxtjs: How to use HttpOnly Cookies for Nuxt-Auth strategy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I worked previously with Vuejs and decided to take a look into NuxtJs. In my previous applications my server sends a HttpOnly cookie which my client couldn't read. So for auth I tried out NuxtAuth which has some startegies and I noticed that it is not possible to use a HttpOnly cookie as strategy. I think this is the limitation of the SSR. But is there a way to use HttpOnly Cookies with NuxtJs? My solution was to run API request only on Client-Side where I have the cookie. This seems to work but I think this is maybe not the ideal solution.

So furthermore how can I setup axios for dev an prod env's in the nuxt.config? When I use the baseURL attribute I got always cors so I tried the proxy which works but the cookies are rejected with the message: The cookie "access_token_cookie" was declined due to invalid domain rights. I thinks this is because the proxy is localhost in dev right? Is there a solution for that?

So any ideas how I can implement HttpOnly authtentication in Nuxt?

Comment: check out [the issue for implementing this](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/142#issuecomment-744051532) which says [the cookie strategy](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/cookie/) now supports http-only... personally, I'm still trying to adapt my auth patterns to universal apps [in a more DIY way](https://vadosware.io/post/cookie-authentication-without-nuxt-auth/) as that nuxt plugin is far from API stable yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily set `httpOnly` cookie options to `true`:

```
auth: {
  cookie: {
    options: {
      httpOnly: true
    },
  },
}
```

I recommend you check the environment to be `true` only on production environment. Because if it is set to `false` on development, the token cookie is not accessable! You can write it like this:

```
httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
```

In [nuxt auth documentation](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/options#cookie), This option is not mentioned! But it works for me :)

Comment: Thanks, it was interesting!
You can set `sameSite` as well 