# Best way to authenticate via Nuxt.js and Nuxt-auth.js

Tags: vue.js, security, nuxt.js, xss, nuxt-auth

I am new to Nuxt.js and having some authentication problem. Hope you guys can have a look.

I am using module `nuxt-auth` of Nuxt.js, when I login, it saves JWT created from cookie to dev console. This makes the site vulnerable to XSS attack. People can read the JWT in the dev console as in the picture below.

[image]

What I tried to fix was setting the login response sent back from the server with the `set-cookie` to `HttpOnly`. But then **nuxt-auth cannot read it**. So my question is:

1. Is there a *better authentication solution for nuxt.js*? or
2. what is the *best practice for using nuxt-auth?*

Any help would be much appreciated! As I this is a very serious security for my application.

[Nuxtjs: How to use HttpOnly Cookies for Nuxt-Auth strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65642232/nuxtjs-how-to-use-httponly-cookies-for-nuxt-auth-strategy)

https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/142

---

Below are what I found when looking up for a solution, but still cannot get it: